# Mac app: Button frames and images invisible after view controller transition

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, segue

After a transition, the button design and image content is missing in the running app. It looks like this:

[image: View in Xcode and in the app]

The code for my custom segue is like this:

```
override func perform() {

    // build from-to and parent-child view controller relationships
    let sourceViewController  = self.sourceController as! NSViewController
    let destinationViewController = self.destinationController as! NSViewController
    let containerViewController = sourceViewController.parent! as NSViewController

    // add destinationViewController as child
    containerViewController.insertChildViewController(destinationViewController, at: 1)

    //perform transition
    containerViewController.transition(from: sourceViewController, to: destinationViewController, options: NSViewControllerTransitionOptions.slideLeft, completionHandler: nil)

    // lose the sourceViewController, it's no longer visible
    containerViewController.removeChildViewController(at: 0)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess. But it looks like your window is a visual effect view/window combo. Which is fine. But I think the default behavior is for all subviews to adopt the "vibrancy" appearance. Which can have weird behaviors with images because it tries to use the alpha channels of the image to make certain effects. Have you tried setting the "allowsVibrancy" property of the image view or its parent view to NO?

Comment: Cannot assign to property: `allowsVibrancy` is a get-only property.

Comment: You are right, it's an NSVisualEffectView – but what is then the recommended method to add images to such a view, and why are the buttons not drawn until I hover them (apparently, until I cause a redraw)?